# vimdiff show differences with only parent rows

Tags: linux, diff, vimdiff

Two config files contain many blocks of the form

```
block name {
  .....
  sub block name1 {
      .........
      sub block name2 {
          ....
      }
  }
  .....
}
```

Example:

Input (LHS) :

```
ltm pool PROD_VAS_START_STOP1_1234 {
   allow-nat yes
   allow-snat yes
   app-service none
   autoscale-group-id none
   description PROD_VAS_START_STOP1_1234
   gateway-failsafe-device none
   ignore-persisted-weight disabled
   ip-tos-to-client pass-through
   ip-tos-to-server pass-through
   link-qos-to-client pass-through
   link-qos-to-server pass-through
   load-balancing-mode round-robin
   members {
       PROD_10.10.10.10:8560 {
           address 10.20.30.40%4
           app-service none
           connection-limit 0
           description none
           dynamic-ratio 1
           ephemeral false
           inherit-profile enabled
           logging disabled
           monitor default
           priority-group 0
           rate-limit disabled
           ratio 1
           session user-disabled
           state user-down
           fqdn {
               autopopulate disabled
               name none  // For ex this line is different b/w two files
           }
           metadata none
           profiles none
       }
       PROD_10.10.10.30:1260 {
           address 10.10.22.30%4
```

The expected output as below:

```
Output  (LHS):

ltm pool PROD_VAS_START_STOP1_1234 {
        members {
               PROD_10.10.10.10:8560 {
                          fqdn {
                                  name none  // For ex this line is different b/w two files
```

Now with `vimdiff`, I am able see the differences storing as html as below. But I want to see the full parentage block rows if at least one difference is there within a block.

The command I use as below.

```
vimdiff out1.txt out2.txt -C 6 -c TOhtml -c 'w! diff1.html' -c 'qa!'
```

[image: diff missing belonging ltm entry]

Comment: You could look at `meld`, which shows all the lines in both files (or all files if you compare three), homes in on differences, allows editing and copying between the files, and integrates with file managers such as `nautilus` and `caja`, as well as being runnable from the command line.